# Поисковик на Python

Tags: python

Необходимо ежедневно проверять десятки сайтов на наличие конкретных текстов внутри них (текст может располагаться на произвольной веб странице внутри сайта ). Хотелось бы сделать такой поисковик на Python. Помогите, пожалуйста, с чего начать реализацию?

Comment: Сайты известны?

Comment: Сайты каждый день новые, входным параметром для начала работы скрипта должен являться именно url. Структуры сайтов и все, что касается их наполнения неопределены.

Comment: Тогда вам нужно писать паук

Answer (score 1):

Изучить стоит:
1. Requests- для работы с web-ресурсами.
2. Beautiful Soup - для парсинга сайтов(если знаете структуру)
3. Re - ругулярные выражения, для поиска текста . Можно использовать другие способы поиска, например алгоритмы а-ля Боэра-Мура-Хорпсула

Самый простой способ это получить текст нужных страниц и тут же, без парсинга, искать нужный текст